# How to use hash_map with char* and do string compare?

Tags: c++, string, stl, hashmap

I was using `std::hash_map<char*,T>` and somehow managed to make it work but have now discovered that the default compare function, `euqal_to<char*>` does a pointer compare rather than a string compare. I've fixed this by making my own compare type (using C's `strcmp` and it's about 5 LOC) but I'd be slightly shocked if there wasn't one already as part of the STL.

*So, is there a comparator for doing string comparison?*

---

[Related link](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2001-05/msg00202.html)

Comment: hash_map is not part of the C++ standard. Which one are you using? Dinkumware, the SGI version, or ....?

Comment: hash_map isn't standard? (I hope that's "not yet")... SGI, I think

Comment: @BCS: The standard container is an `unordered_map`, a `hash_map` is a nonstandard extention.

Comment: What's the important differences?

Comment: hash_map was never standardized, it remained a non-standard extension. SGI provided one and so did Dinkumware. unordered_map is in TR1 and will be in C++0x. There isn't a lot different between them, but they couldn't use the name hash_map as it was already in wide use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `std::strcmp` is defined by C++ when you do `#include <cstring>`.  The example in [SGI's hash_map doc](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html) provides a `strcmp`-based example of making your own equality-testing function for char*'s (quoting from beginning of the SGI doc):

```
struct eqstr
{
  bool operator()(const char* s1, const char* s2) const
  {
    return strcmp(s1, s2) == 0;
  }
};
```

I have to say I agree with the author of the [link in your post](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2001-05/msg00202.html), where he says that it is already a mistake for `hash_map<char*>` to use by default a string-based `hash<char*>`.  But I usually use hash_maps (or, lately, boost::unordered_maps) on C++ std::strings for this kind of thing anyway.

Comment: I'll accept the point on the default, however I'd think providing a pre-built option would be good idea.

Comment: this is effectively what I did and I'd be surprised if the docs would use it as an example of there was a better way.

Comment: I agree, it would make sense if `namespace std` provided string-oriented alternatives for `std::less<char*>` and `std::equal<char*>`. But those should be alternative names, not specializations.

Answer (score 0):

The STL has a `find` method for the string type. This allow you to find a string in the string but you can use it for comparing 2 strings.

Otherwise you have a [comparison function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/) for std::string vars.

Any of this vars can be constructed with a char*.